# MongoDB atlas PHPLIB

Tags: php, mongodb, phplib

I've got this error:

```
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: Failed to look up SRV record "_mongodb._tcp.training.gd45p.mongodb.net": No such file or directory
```

While executing this code:

```php
$mongo = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb+srv://admin:{mypassword}@training.gd45p.mongodb.net/{db}?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

$db = $mongo->test->users;


$result = $db->insertOne(['name' => 'Tom', 'role' => 'admin']);
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: DNS resolution is broken on your machine for SRV records or you have some weird PHP installation issue.